# Accessing keys of a dictionary within dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a few functions defined to set up some dictionaries and organize things. What I'm trying to do now is use a nested dictionary as a function parameter for another function.

K so I have this inputted format:

```
list = {'123': {'Name': 'foo', 'Responses': {'Q4': 'a', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'b', 'Q3': 'c'}, 'ID': '123'}, '234': {'Name': 'bar', 'Responses': {'Q4': 'b', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'b', 'Q3': 'c'}, 'ID': '234'}, '345': {'Name': 'xyzzy', 'Responses': {'Q4': 'b', 'Q1': 'a', 'Q2': 'a', 'Q3': 'c'}, 'ID': '345'}}
```

I need to access the 'Responses' key so that the function can use the Q1, Q2, etc keys and compare to another dictionart. And i need to do this for each 123, 234, 345 keys. 
Then not so significant i have to map a key key for the values that function gives and update a list but I can figure that out once i get this function to run.

I've tried using list.get('Responses') as the parameter but it returns None so I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.get()` parameter looks for top level keys. What you actually probably want is to list over the sub-level dictionaries:

```
for key, sub_dict in toplevel_dict.items():
    responses = sub_dict['Responses']
    # do something with responses here; responses is a dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows using a list comprehension :

```
l = [dic['Responses'] for _, dic in list.items()]
# You get a list of all your dictionaries
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a for loop with iteritems to pull out the info.

```
for key, value in list.iteritems():
    print value['Responses']
```